# how to include % sign in docutils html template

Tags: python

I want to generate HTML pages with rst2html, using my own templates. these templates include many % signs, like in

```
<TABLE border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

now, when I call rst2html using the command

```
rst2html --template=layout2.tpl rst/index.rst > index.html
```

i get the error

> ValueError: unsupported format character '"' (0x22) at index 827

i found out the problem is that rst2html thinks that the %" is a placeholder.

i already tried escaping the % in the template, like

```
<TABLE border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100\%">
```

but this is not working, the error is the same.

so my question is how i can solve this issue. any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure it's the "%" and not some other non-ASCII character?  Have you tried forcing the file to be pure ASCII?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried obvious things: escaping the '%' with '%'?

Here is normal string formatting to display a percent sign in the result:

```
>>> print "%d%%" % 100
100%
```

Maybe rst2html is the same? (I haven't tried this in rst2html -- I don't have it installed.)

Okay, now I've installed docutils. This works for me:

layout2.tpl:

```
<TABLE border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%%">
```

Command line:

```
C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages>python C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\docutils-0.5-
py2.6.egg\EGG-INFO\scripts\rst2html.py --template=c:\temp\layout2.tpl
^Z
<TABLE border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

So the result is as desired, I believe.

Comment: hmm. when i put the line

<TABLE border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100'%'">

i still get

ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 827

so the obvious is not working here -- or i'm doing something wrong ...

Comment: yep, that's it. the following works: <TABLE border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%%">

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Doubt it, but maybe the XML command CDATA works.

```
<![CDATA[
...
]]>
```

I use it for storing paypal buttons in an XML document and inserting them with PHP.